# Showing that $|f(a+v) - f(a) - T\dot\,v| \leq \sup_{0<t<1} |f'(a+tv) - T|\dot\,|v|$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

**Question:**

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb R^n$ continuous at the open subset $U \subset \mathbb R^m$, and consider the line segment $[a, a+v ] \subset U$. If $f$ is diferentiable at all points $(a, a+v)$ with $f|_{[a,a+v]}$ continuous, then, for every $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^m ; \mathbb R^n)$, show that 
>   $$|f(a+v) - f(a) - T\dot\,v| \leq \sup_{0<t<1} |f'(a+tv) - T|\dot\,|v|$$

**Attempt:** Let $g: U \to \mathbb R^n$ be defined as $g(x) = f(x) - T\dot\, x$. We have that as $f$ is differentiable at $(a, a+v ) \subset U$ and $T$ is a linear transformation, therefore differentiable, then $g$ is differentiable at $(a,a+v)$.

Notice that $g'(x) =f'(x) - T$ and $$|g'(a+ tv)|= |f'(a+tv) - T| \leq |f'(a + tv)| + |T| \leq M , \,\, \forall t \in (0,1)$$

where $M = \tilde M + \sup \{|T\dot \, u| ; u \in  S^{n-1}\}$, and $\tilde M$ exists because $f|_{[a,a+v]}$ is continuous and attains to a maximum. Now usind the Mean Value Inequality to the function $g$ comes

$$|f(a + v) - f(a) -T\dot\, v| = |g(a + v ) - g(a)| \leq M \dot \, |v|$$

I know this proof is somehow inconsistent. I was wondering what can be improved.

**Note:** I am not interested in different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $g(t) = f(a+tv)-T(a+tv) $. $g$ is a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and 
$$g'(t) = (f'(a+tv) - T)(v)$$
$$\begin{align} &|f(a + v) - f(a) -T\cdot\, v|  \\
&= |g(1) - g(0)| \\
&= \left|\int_0^1 (f'(a+tv) - T)( v )\mathrm{d}t\right| \\
&\leqslant \int_0^1\sup_{0<t<1} |f'(a+tv) - T|\cdot |v | \mathrm{d}t \quad \mbox{ (We apply the Mean Value Inequality here)}\\
&= \sup_{0<t<1} |f'(a+tv) - T|\cdot|v|
\end{align} $$

Comment: What is the domain of $g$?

Comment: $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: You haven't used the Mean Value Thorem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've seen this approach on one of the Theorems and thought of using it. But this result is a Corollary of the Mean Value Theorem, so I though of trying to use it.

Comment: The former answer is a bit flawed and I made a correction. In fact the $f'(a+tv)$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $T$ does.

Comment: For the "Mean Value Theorem" it is evidently used from line 1 to line 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24940/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-corindo).